# How to view all values under single category?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

I have a dataframe like this-

| Category | Tags |
| --- | --- |
| National | Politics, President |
| sports | Football, tennis |
| Economy | Inflation |
| sports | Cricket |

I want to see how many tags are in under different category and transform my dataframe into like this -

```
Category            Tags           Count
sports              Football       3
                    tennis
                    Cricket

National            Politics       2
                    President      

Economy             Inflation      1
```

I tried this but not getting accurate results-

```
df.groupby(['category','tags'])['tags'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming lists, use:

```
(df.explode('Tags')
   .assign(Count=lambda d: d.groupby('Category')['Tags'].transform('count'))
   .sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
)
```

If you have strings:

```
(df.assign(Tags=df['Tags'].str.split(',\s*'))
   .explode('Tags')
   .assign(Count=lambda d: d.groupby('Category')['Tags'].transform('count'))
   .sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
)
```

output:

```
   Category       Tags  Count
0    sports   Football      3
1    sports     tennis      3
2    sports    Cricket      3
3  National   Politics      2
4  National  President      2
5   Economy  Inflation      1
```